# Three table join where middle table has duplicate foreign keys

Tags: sql, oracle, join

I am working with a database with a structure similar to the illustration below (except with more columns).  Basically, each person has a unique person_id and alt_id.  However, the only thing connecting table A to table C is table B, and table B has one to many rows for each person/alt_id.

I need to get rows with a person_id, their alt id and their associated shapes.

I could do this:

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.person_id, a.color, b.alt_id, c.shape 
 FROM a 
 JOIN b ON a.person_id = b.person_id
 JOIN c ON b.alt_id = c.alt_id
```

However, that seems inefficient as it will take a Cartesian product of rows from B and C with the same alt_id before finally using DISTINCT to narrow the results down.  What's the best/most efficient way to do this query?

```
Table A

+-----------+-------+
| person_id | color |
+-----------+-------+
|        10 | red   |
|        11 | blue  |
|        12 | green |
+-----------+-------+

Table B
+-----------+--------+
| person_id | alt_id |
+-----------+--------+
|        10 |    225 |
|        10 |    225 |
|        11 |    226 |
|        11 |    226 |
|        11 |    226 |
|        12 |    227 |
+-----------+--------+

Table C
+--------+----------+
| alt_id |  shape   |
+--------+----------+
|    225 | square   |
|    226 | circle   |
|    226 | rhombus  |
|    226 | ellipse  |
|    227 | triangle |
+--------+----------+
```

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Join to `(select distinct * from b) b` rather than just the base table `b`.

```
SELECT
    a.person_id, a.color, b.alt_id, c.shape 
FROM
    a
    INNER JOIN (select distinct * from b) b
        ON a.person_id = b.person_id
    INNER JOIN c
        ON b.alt_id = c.alt_id
```

Answer (score 1):

You can get a distinct list of values from `b` before you do your joins.

```
SELECT DISTINCT a.person_id, a.color, b.alt_id, c.shape 
FROM a 
JOIN (Select Distinct person_id, alt_id from b) b ON a.person_id = b.person_id
JOIN c ON b.alt_id = c.alt_id
```

Note that because of indexes, and statistics, getting a `DISTINCT` list is not always a good idea. Look at the actual execution plan to evaluate how good this is, especially if you have a lot of data.

Answer (score 1):

You could use aggregation along with a common table expression (or subquery, but a CTE might be neater):

```
WITH ab AS (
    SELECT a.person_id, a.color, MAX(b.alt_id) AS alt_id
      FROM a INNER JOIN b
        ON a.person_id = b.person_id
     GROUP BY a.person_id, a.color
)
SELECT ab.person_id, ab.color, ab.alt_id, c.shape
  FROM ab INNER JOIN c ON ab.alt_id = c.alt_id;
```